# Toast: Docs' tutorials say to use getApplicationContext, but Docs References say to use getApplication or getActivity

Tags: android, android-context, toast, android-toast

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts: in the sources examples, they use `getApplicationContext`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int): "Context: The context to use. Usually your Application or Activity object.".

**What should we use in definitive?**

To answer this question, I think one should think about...:

- The lifecycle of the object `Toast` defined in a fragment, and then the lifecycle of `Toast` defined in an activity
- The risk of memory leaks if we use `getActivity`, which depends on the `Toast`

https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-context-in-android-application-330913e32514: here, it seems that one should use `getActivity` for `Toast`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should we use in definitive?

Generally speaking: if the `Context` is being applied to something for the UI, use the `Activity`, so that your current theme can be taken into account. `Toast` is UI; therefore, use the `Activity`.

In reality, I don't think that a `Toast` necessarily uses anything from the theme.

> The lifecycle of the object Toast defined in a fragment, and then the lifecycle of Toast defined in an activity

Those are the same thing, since a fragment is unrelated to a `Toast`. You do not pass a `Fragment` to any method on `Toast`.

> The risk of memory leaks if we use getActivity, which depends on the Toast

Since the `Toast` is short-lived, any possible leak is short-lived. Leaks are a problem when the leaked material is referenced for an indefinite period of time and so will not get cleaned up.

Comment: I have ready that, even if Toast is UI, its lifecycle is bound to the application's lifecycle. So that we should not use getActivity but getApplicationContext, which can not be found in a Fragment Ithout calling getActivity which can return null if the fragment is detached from the activity before. So: 1) Is a Toadt really bound to the application lifecycle (contradiction with your answer) and 2) if yes: how could we use the application context in a fragment without calling getActivity?

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler: "1) Is a Toadt really bound to the application lifecycle (contradiction with your answer)" -- since there is no "application lifecycle", a `Toast` is not bound to that. "how could we use the application context in a fragment without calling getActivity?" -- you can't. However, if `getActivity()` returns `null`, the fragment should not be doing any UI work anyway.

Comment: https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-context-in-android-application-330913e32514 says " This context [getApplicationContext] is tied to the lifecycle of an application.". Another way to ask my question could be: is the lifecycle of a toast a strict subset of the lifecycle of the activity? If yes: I must use `getActivity`, otherwise `getApplicationContext`?

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler: "is the lifecycle of a toast a strict subset of the lifecycle of the activity?" -- no. "If yes: I must use getActivity, otherwise getApplicationContext?" -- I cover this in my answer.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the leak would be short-lived so it's not really a problem. Am I right?

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler: Correct. Worry about long-lived leaks; worry less about short-lived ones.

Comment: Hum :-/ I don't find it very clear... It would be so better if it one can avoid **any** memory leaks, right?

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler: You are welcome to your opinion. My opinion is that developers are better served with a rule of "use the activity for UI-related concerns", even if that results in a short-term memory leak with a `Toast`. IMHO, if you are using a `Toast` for anything beyond a sample app, your app has UX issues.